# Создать функцию хранилище по шаблону ниже

Tags: javascript

Я нашла что-то вроде этого, создаю функцию, которая должна иметь пустой объект внутри, и эта функция возвращает объект, в котором есть ключи — это все наши методы, которые мы можем вызвать позже

```
 Storage.Value('key', 'value')
    function name () {
        let obj = {}   
        return {
            setName: (key, value) => {
                obj[key] = value
             },
         }
     }
    const Name = name();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю вам использовать классы, а не функции т.к. классы больше подходят по смыслу чем функции в данном случае. Ниже простой пример как это можно реализовать.

P.s. Рекомендую вам использовать `setProp` и `getProp` (или любое другое название, которое больше подходит по смыслу) вместо `setValue` и `getValue`. Потому что вы не всегда устанавливаете новое значение, но и объявляете ранее не существующее св-во

```js
class Storage {
    setValue(property, value) {
        this[property] = value;
    }
    
    getValue(property) {
        return this[property];
    }
}

const propsStorage = new Storage();
propsStorage.setValue('name', 'Mike');
propsStorage.setValue('age', 16);
console.log(propsStorage.getValue('name')); // Mike
console.log(propsStorage.getValue('age')); // 16
propsStorage.setValue('age', 20);
console.log(propsStorage.getValue('age')); // 20
console.log(propsStorage.getValue('secondName')); // undefined
```